# Getting Value from DataView C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dataview

How to find a value of some column from DataView.CurrentItem.

Comment: There is no DataView member named CurrentItem.  Do you mean DataView indexer?  Or a DataGrid.CurrentRow or DataGridView.CurrentRow?

Comment: Sorry it is not DataView.CurrentItem it is CollectionViewSource.CurrentItem

Comment: I figured out now I am using dt.Rows[CollectionViewSource.CurrentPosition]["ColumnName"].ToString(), is there a better way to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Paul pointed out in his comment, there is no `CurrentItem` member in the `DataView` class.

If you know the index of the item, you can access a column by its name as shown below :

```
string name = dataView[index]["Name"] as string;
```

Similarly, if you have an instance of a `DataRowView` (a view of a `DataRow`), you can do that :

```
string name = dataRowView["Name"] as string;
```

---

EDIT: I just noticed the WPF tag on your question... perhaps you're talking about a `CollectionView`, not `DataView` ?

`CollectionView` doesn't have "columns" per se, but it can be represented in a `GridView` or `DataGrid` (which both have columns). It's just a view over a collection of objects. To access a specific field or property of the current object, there are two main options :

- if you statically know the actual type of the collection items : cast the `CurrentItem` to that type, and directly access the members you need
- if you don't know the type, you can use reflection on the CurrentItem to access its properties or fields by name

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using following dt.Rows[CollectionViewSource.CurrentPosition]["ColumnName"].ToString() where colloectionViewSource is bound to DataContext .